# How to specify default behaviour for wingrid features

Tags: infragistics, ultrawingrid

When you drop a grid on a form and go through the wizard there are a number of places where "Default Behavior" is an option (for example, under Features -> Updating -> Allow Row Adding). Where do you set these default behaviours? We tend to have far more read only grids than updateable ones, so if I could specify this default behaviour somewhere for an entire application it would save having to remember to do it individually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A 'Default' value in the context of an override object means that it is going to default to the value defined higher up in the heirarchy (column -> band -> grid).  If the top level object is also set to 'Default' it is going to resolve to the default behavior as intended by Infragistics; this is not user definable.

In the specific case of AllowAddNew, the "default" behavior depends on the context. If the grid is not attached to a data source it will be No, otherwise it will be Yes.

Answer (score 1):

You could use Presets for setting up default options.  When you manage presets there is an option to have a specific preset applied to grids created at design time.  You can use the [WinGrid designer](http://help.infragistics.com/NetAdvantage/WinForms/Current/CLR2.0/?page=WinGrid_Using_the_WinGrid_Designer.html) to access presets.

Comment: That's a good idea, I'll take a look. I've tended to ignore presets since we started getting heavilly into appstylist, but it sounds like I need to revisit then